# The order of a modular form is invariant under the action of $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

I am reading Serre's a course in arithmetic and I am very confused about the invariance of the order of a modular function (as a meromorphic function) under $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ action:

The order at $p$ of a meromorphic function $f$ is $v_p(f):=n$, where $n$ is the integer such that $f/(z-p)^n$ is analytic and nonzero at $p$. The following is a screenshot of the book:

[image]

Serre says the invariance follows from the identity in the definition of modular forms, but I don't see why. Specifically,

let $g=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ 
c & d
\end{bmatrix}$ be a matrix in $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$, let $v_p(f)=n$, the goal is to show that

$$\frac{f(z)}{(z-g.p)^n}=\frac{f(\frac{az+b}{cz+d})}{(cz+d)^{2k}(z-\frac{ap+b}{cp+d})^n}$$

is nonvanishing and holomorphic at $p$. But it is very unclear to me why this should be true. Maybe I am looking at it in the wrong way. Thanks for help!

---

Update:

From Parthiv's answer below it seems that the interpretation should really be for $g \in SL_2(\mathbb Z)$

(1) $v_p(f)=v_p(f\circ g)$

instead of

(2) $v_p(f)=v_{g(p)}(f)$

But now I wish to see a counterexample for (2) (I don't have a handy example for modular functions).

Comment: I thought about it. I think it's obvious why the second interpretation shouldn't hold.  Say $f(z)$ has a zero of order $1$ at $p$, then we have that $h(z)$ in $f(z)=h(z)(z-p)$ is holomorphic and nonzero at $p$. So for $g$ such that $gp \neq p$, we have that $\frac{(z-p)h(z)}{(z-gp)}$ is zero at $p$.

Comment: @ParthivBasu Thanks! And is it easy to come up with a modular function $f$ with zero of order $1$ at $p$?

Comment: Finding the zeros of modular functions in general is a catastrophically hard problem. But they do exist. I don't have any simple examples, you have to confront the literature.

Comment: @ParthivBasu Thanks!

Comment: I went through my notes again. The modular form $E_4$ has a simple zero at $\rho := e^{2\pi i /3}$. In my notes this is proven using the valence formula. But there is a much simpler to see that this is a zero. The fact that $\rho^2 + \rho + 1 =0$ implies for the lattice $L_{\rho} = \rho \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}$ that $\rho L_\rho = L_\rho$. But then $E_4(\rho) = \rho^4 E_4(\rho)$, which implies $E_4(\rho) =0 $.

Comment: Sorry for reactivating this thread after seven months, but I am a bit confused about this interpretation. With $q:=g(p)$, shouldn't the very definition of $v_q(f)$ (which is equal to $v_{g(p)}(f)$) as given by Serre in the first line of section 3.1 mean the maximal integer $n$ for which $f(z)/(z-q)^n = f(z)/(z-g(p))^n$ is holomorphic and non-zero at $q$? Moreover if $v_{g(p)}(f)$ actually meant $v_p(fg)$, then the statement "$v_p(f)$ depends only on the image of $p$ in $H/G$" would be false (as the order of $f$ at $g(p)$ would be different from $v_p(fg)$ in general, right? (Continued below.)

Comment: (Continued from above) Furthermore, in that case the valence relation would also have to contain all the orders of $f$ at every $g(p)$ (for every $p \in H$) and the relations $(19)$ and $(20)$ (in the chapter) would not make sense (as $v_p(f)$ would then depend on the representative $p$ chosen from each orbit in $H/G$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A modular function of weight $k$ (odd weighted modular functions are identically zero but a priori we don't know that) is meromorphic on the upper half-plane and satisfies $f(gz) = (cz+d)^k f(z)$ for all $g \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Since $cz+d$ is holomorphic and not equal to zero on the upper half-plane, we have that $(cz+d)^k f(z)$ and $f(z)$ have the same order. By $n = v_{g(p)}(f)$, Serre means $n$ such that $\frac{f(gz)}{(z-p)^n} = (cz+d)^k \frac{f(z)}{(z-p)^n}$ is holomorphic and nonzero in $p$.

Comment: Are you sure the concerned formula for $n = v_{g(p)}(f)$ is $\frac{f(gz)}{(z-p)^n}$ instead of $\frac{f(z)}{(z-g(p))^n}$? I think we are supposed to replace $p$ by $g(p)$ instead of $f$ by $f(g())$. Otherwise we should use $v_p(f\circ g)$

Comment: Yes I am sure about it. This property is mentioned at the beginning of every text on modular forms. So it'd be weird if Serre has something else in mind.

Comment: Actually Serre also says $v_p(f)$ depends only on the image of $p$ in $\mathbb H /G$ where $G=PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$ (the last sentence of the picture. I forgot to include the other half). I don't know how to justify this.

Comment: Are you familiar with fundamental domains? See in particular the section on fundamental domain  for the full modular group (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain)

Comment: Yes, I know the definition at least.

Comment: What I meant in the previous comment was that it seems that Serre really wants to move $p$ around instead of translating the function. So I am very confused and thus need a justification for that

Comment: I understand Serre's  text as follows. If we know the values of the modular function on the fundamental domain, then we can determine the values of the modular function on all of the upper half-plane. In the usual interpretation, the order of a modular function is invariant under the action of the full modular group. So it suffices to know its order in the fundamental domain.

Comment: Yes I agree. Now do you have an example that shows $v_p(f)=v_{g(p)}(f)$ actually fails if we take it literally?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. I have to think about it.

Comment: Sure, thanks for your help!